# swift 3 - http authentication in WKWebView

Tags: swift, swift3, wkwebview, http-authentication

I'm trying to build a simple WebView which shows a web page - the page requires http authentication for all pages (for testing purposes).

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    // #1 variant
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge:
        URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let user = "user"
        let password = "pass"
        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
    }

    // #2 variant
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

            let user = "user"
            let password = "pass"
            let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
            challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://myurl.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

}
```

I've found willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge and didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge, but none of them is called and I've got error from the server that I was not authenticated.

Could somebody help?

Thank you a lot!

David

Comment: Fixed variant #1 by adding "_":

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        
            let user = "user"
            let password = "pass"
            let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
            challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, credential)
    }

Comment: Did you mean to use WKUIDelegate? I extended my view controller class with WKNavigationDelegate (setting webView.navigationDelegate = self instead of webView.uiDelegate = self) and implimented the following function:    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

Comment: yes, I shared the answer already below

Comment: Interesting, my completion handler wasn't getting called until I changed WKUIDelegate to WKNavigationDelegate and webView.uiDelegate = self to  webView.navigationDelegate = self

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed variant #1 by adding "_":

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        let user = "user"
        let password = "pass"
        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, credential)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works by removing (or comment out) this line.
`challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)`
I have checked it also in other iOS versions 9.X, 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3.
It's working fine.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let user = "user"
    let password = "pass"
    let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, credential)
```

}