# How to handle authentication challenge in WKWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, ssl-certificate, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebview` and trying to connect a server(***HTTPS***) that server is running inside my application with self-signed certificate but `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method got invoked with error.

```
The certificate for this server is authroized by valid CA.
You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
--My URL-- which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I added the below code in the delegate method to bypass this and proceed.

```
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    CFDataRef exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions (serverTrust);
    SecTrustSetExceptions (serverTrust, exceptions);
    CFRelease (exceptions);
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
    completionHandler (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
```

My Question is Since it should not be done when it goes to the app store. How I have to handle this?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455638-webview?language=objc) delegate method?

Comment: Yes. I have clearly mentioned this in my question

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960700/swift-3-http-authentication-in-wkwebview

Comment: @CtrlAltDel My server doesn't have user name/ password.  So that post is not applicable for me